# Creating monads analoguous to the IO Monad with chained state

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

Hello folks,

I'm pretty new to Haskell again this year (after using it in the early 1990s and then again in the early 00's). I'm trying to write some code that uses a pattern that is almost directly analoguous to the [example IO monad shown on the Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IO_inside#Welcome_to_the_RealWorld.2C_baby):

```hs
type IO a  =  RealWorld -> (a, RealWorld)
```

(Yes, I know this isn't the GHC implementation of IO, but merely a vehicle for understanding it.) The reason is, in my application (a game), I now have two patterns doing this with two different substitutions of the `RealWorld` here. In one, it's the state of the game, and in the other, it's just a `StdGen` random number seed. I of course now have two pairs of types like this:

```hs
-- | Easily return a specified value as well as the new random number generator
type ReturnRNG a = (a, StdGen)

-- | Take an RNG and return it and another value.
-- (This is basically like the IO type but with the StdGen instead of RealWorld.)
type WithRNG a = StdGen -> ReturnRNG a

-- | Easily return a specified value as well as the new GameState
type ReturnGS a = (a, GameState)

-- | Use a GameState and return a value with the updated GameState.
-- (This is like IO.)
type WithGS a = GameState -> ReturnGS a
```

(Yes, I could abstract them into one pair with two parameters but I haven't gotten around to it.) You can see, of course, that my `WithGS a` and `WithRNG a` types (type synonyms) are exactly analogous to `IO a` above.

So, here's a simple example of actual working code that I now have:

```hs
-- | Returns a random position for the given size.
randomPos :: (Int, Int)          -- ^ The size
          -> WithRNG (Int, Int)  -- ^ The result (0 up to 1 less than the size) and new RNG seed
randomPos (w, h) r0 = ((x, y), r2)
  where
    (x, r1) = randomR (0, w - 1) r0
    (y, r2) = randomR (0, h - 1) r1
```

This creates a random pair in a specified range, and returns the final RNG seed. A large percentage of my methods are like this (using `WithRNG` or `WithGS`), using a chained state, sometimes even getting up to `r4` or `r6` (or `gs4`, etc.). I'd rather write this example to look like this...

```hs
-- (Not working example)
randomPosSt (w, h) = do
    x <- randomR (0, w - 1)
    y <- randomR (0, h - 1)
    return (x, y)
```

...yet have the exact same method signature and semantics. This seems like it should be possible following the aforementioned tutorial which gives this example:

```hs
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
(action1 >>= action2) world0 =
   let (a, world1) = action1 world0
       (b, world2) = action2 a world1
   in (b, world2)
```

This, as you can see, is almost exactly what I'm doing above (once you substitute "`let`" for "`where`" notation).

However, I cannot create a Monad out of a type synonym. (I've tried TypeSynonymInstances but it doesn't seem to work with either "`instance Monad WithRNG where`" or using a parameter. Using a `newtype` would also seem to add useless ugly syntax.) I haven't been able to figure out the State Monad well enough to make an equivalent method using that either. Even if I had succeeded, however, the State Monad implementation would seem to use ugly "`get`" and "`put`"s (and "`runState`"s etc.) and make the code *less* readable, not more.

```hs
-- THIS DOES NOT WORK
-- | Make a State Monad with random number generator - like WithRNG above
type RandomState = State StdGen

-- | Returns a random position for the given size.
randomPosSt :: (Int, Int)                  -- ^ The size
            -> RandomState (Int, Int)  -- ^ The result (0 up to 1 less than the size) and new RNG seed
```

After all this, I've concluded that I'm either doing something wrong, misunderstanding something, or just can't do what I want to do. I was just about to say "well, you don't really need to figure out how to modify your code to make the state carried through to be handled automatically, as it works just fine" and give up and then I thought I'd ask here (my debut delurking). I would prefer a more elegant solution.

I also figure a more elegant solution would give me this function I use "for free:"

```hs
-- | Maps the specified method, which must take a RNG as the last parameter,
-- over all the elements of the list, propagating the RNG and returning it.
-- TODO: Implement this without using recursion? Using a fold?
mapRandom :: (a -> WithRNG b) -- ^ The function to map (that takes a RNG)
          -> [a] -- ^ The input list
          -> WithRNG [b] -- ^ The RNG to return
mapRandom func [] r0 = ([], r0)
mapRandom func (x:xs) r0 = (mapped : rest, r2)
  where
    (mapped, r1) = func x r0
    (rest, r2)   = mapRandom func xs r1
```

Thanks for any thoughts, suggestions, references and your time!

Comment: Before I answer, are you aware of the `State` monad?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Indeed I have heard of the State monad: "I haven't been able to figure out the State Monad well enough to make an equivalent method using that either. Even if I had succeeded, however, the State Monad implementation would seem to use ugly "get" and "put"s (and "runStates" etc.) and make the code less readable, not more."

Comment: Before I answer, are you aware of the [`RandT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.8/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html) monad transformer?

Comment: @DanielWagner I have come across that, yes. I didn't understand it, and the example given didn't seem to accomplish what I was looking to do. (Additionally, I'm looking to extend the metaphor to chained state other than just the random number generator.) Also, I don't already have any monads in use in my application, except for IO. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `State` monad without using `get` or `put`.  Just wrap your state passing functions directly in the `State` newtype:

```
import System.Random

newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }

instance Monad (State s) where
    return a = State (\s -> (a, s))

    m >>= f = State (\s0 ->
        let (a, s1) = runState m s0
        in  runState (f a) s1 )

randomPos :: (Int, Int) -> State StdGen (Int, Int)
randomPos (w, h) = do
    x <- State $ randomR (0, w - 1)
    y <- State $ randomR (0, h - 1)
    return (x, y)
```

The trick is to observe the type of the `State` constructor:

```
State :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a
```

.. and `randomR (lo, hi)` has just the right type to be wrapped directly within `State`:

```
randomR (1, 6)          :: StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)
StateT $ randomR (1, 6) :: State StdGen Int
```

The `State` constructor takes a state passing function and creates a suitable value for use within a `State` monad.  Then when you are done using the monad you can convert the monad back to the equivalent state-passing function using `runState`:

```
runState :: State s a -> (s -> (a, s))

runState (randomPos (5, 6)) :: StdGen -> ((Int, Int), StdGen)
```

This is in fact how `RandT` works, by wrapping all the generator-passing random functions in a state monad, and `RandT` is equivalent to `StateT StdGen` under the hood.

Also, like you said, the monadic formulation would give you the mapped version for free:

```
mapRandom
    :: ( a  -> (StdGen -> ( b , StdGen)))
    -> ([a] -> (StdGen -> ([b], StdGen)))
mapRandom f xs = runState $ mapM (State . f) xs
```

This is because the type of `mapM` (when specialized to `State`) is:

```
mapM :: (a -> State s b) -> [a] -> State s [b]
```

So all the above `mapRandom` function does is wrap the input in a `State` newtype, use `mapM`, and then unwrap it.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm going to try this on both of my types and see how it looks in my code. I did have two follow-up questions: Why in your answer do you create a <code>State</code> newtype and <code>Monad</code> instance yourself instead of using an import? And, is it not possible to avoid the "State" and "runState" wrapper/unwrappers to get something more elegant like the (putative) <code>IO</code> monad's elegant syntax?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer It's because there is no longer an official implementation of a non-monad-transformer version of `State` in the standard libraries.  If you check out `transformers` and `mtl`, they now both implement `State s` as a type synonym for `StateT s Identity`, and in place of the `State` constructor they provide the `state` function which behaves the same way.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed that the State monad was modified. One final question: Why is the IO monad special? It seems to be implemented exactly like the State monad above but does not need to have the newtype wrapper/unwrapper. I'd love to do away with those somehow. Thanks again. (No idea why it won't take my AT Gabriel or AT GabrielGonzalez.)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Actually, the `IO` monad is not special and it does require the newtype.  The wiki only pretends it is a type synonym for teachin purposes.  You can check out the definition [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.3.0.0/src/GHC-Types.html#IO) to see the newtype for yourself.  There is no way to do away with the newtype unwrapper: it's a fundamental limitation of how the type class system works.  Anything that implements a type class (such as `Monad`) must use a newtype to correctly to reorganize type variables if necessary.

Comment: _(How do I ask a follow-up question?)_ I'm in the middle of converting my code to this State style now, but in the interim I have a lot of functions like "randomPos size = runState (randomPosSt size)". I'd like to figure out a way to do this without having any parameters after - such as (and this doesn't work) "randomPos = runState . randomPosSt". It seems, however, that I cannot do this because it then curries all the parameters to randomPosSt. I can't partially curry all parameters but the last one and leave that on runState. Is there a way to do this? Thanks again!

Comment: I also have a function convertToState as a "helper" (at the end). Is there a generic way to do this for any function using the State monad (as above or as in the existing libraries)? Thanks!  -- | Converts our old style random function to a new style function using Monads.
convertToState :: (a -> WithRNG b) -> (a -> RandomState b)
convertToState func = \a -> state (func a)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Feel free to ask as many questions as you like!  The style where you get rid of parameters is known as "point-free" style.  For example, given `f x y = g (h x y)`, then `f x = g . h x`, which reduces further to `f = (g .) . h`.  However, this style is generally considered unreadable and I'd stick to the "point-ful" form for two or more parameters.  Also, `convertToState f a = runState (f a)` or `convertToState = (runState .)`, or even `convertToState = fmap runState`.  As an aside, functions of the form `a -> m b`, where `m` is some monad, are called Kleisli arrows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28341/discussion-between-software-engineer-and-gabriel-gonzalez)

Comment: I hit the "chat" thing (never saw that before). Thank you yet again for the detailed response. I will try all those compositions you suggested and tear them apart until I fully grok them. Although I do tend to write code in a maintainable and readable manner (I have current production code originally written in the 20th century, after all), I do like to understand all the tricks! (Should we continue here or in that chat thing?) Is it best to use the specific "newtype" monad you suggested above, or to use the State monad from the System.Control.Monad package?

Comment: If you want we can continue by e-mail so we don't have character limits.  My e-mail is Gabriel439 and I use Google's mail service.